# Do something every number of percent

Tags: c#, console-application, percentage

I wanted to make two commands that alternate exactly for the specified number of percentages.

How to do a command in `while` that will do only  a few percent and if not do a different command.

---

I'm trying to create a program to which you give the total number of characters, how many characters it should return and the percentage that determines the ratio between two characters.
e.g.

```cs
decimal r = (decimal)1 / 3 * 100 //r = 33,33...%
string output = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if (r) //go in only on r %
  {
    output += "T "; //return 'T'
  }
  else
  {
    output += "F "; //return 'F'
  }
}
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

```
F F T F F T F F T F
```

Comment: `r` must be regular it can not be random

Comment: Please research "Integer Division". Put down a breakpoint and inspect the value of `r` after it has been assigned, you'll find that it's always 0.

Comment: it must by regular like `F F T F F T F F T F F T F F T` if it will be random it can be `F T F F T F T F F F`

Comment: I don't understand the requirements you're trying to meet. What is the difference between `"total number of characters"` and `"how many characters it should return"`

Comment: it is same. I just want to say that the result must be regular

Comment: What should happen if the percentage is, say, `46%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use the [remainder operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) (`%`) to determine if the counter variable is an occurrence when you need to output `"T"` by using it with `i` and the value of `numChars \ percent`.

In other words, we can determine the occurrences by dividing the total number of characters by the percentage. This number tells us how often we need to output `"T"`. If there are `100` characters, and we pass in `33%`, then, since `100 / 33 == 3`, we know that every `3`rd character should be a `"T"`.

For example:

```
public static void PrintResults(int numChars, int percentage)
{
    // In this implementation, 'percentage' is a whole number, like 33
    // Here we determine what the percentage of numChars is
    var percent = numChars * percentage / 100;

    // And now we can divide numChars by percent to find out
    // how often we need to display the alternate character
    var occurrence = numChars / percent;

    for(int i = 1; i <= numChars; i++)
    {
        // Here we use the remainder operator to determine if this is an 
        // occurrence where we should display the alternate character
        if (i % occurrence == 0) Console.Write("T ");
        else Console.Write("F ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This would then be called like:

```
PrintResults(10, 33);
```

Which would output:

```
F F T F F T F F T F
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the idea of passing a percentage to indicate a ratio is not as good an idea as passing the ratio itself.

Here's a way to do this with a more direct ratio.

Start with an infinite pattern generator that outputs `T` and `F` according to the ratio:

```
public IEnumerable<char> Pattern(int fs, int ts)
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (var f = 0; f < fs; f++) yield return 'F';
        for (var t = 0; t < ts; t++) yield return 'T';
    }
}
```

Now it is trivial to put together the string you're after:

```
//2 F for every 1 T and take 10 in total.
string output = String.Join(" ", Pattern(2, 1).Take(10));
```

The result is this:

```
F F T F F T F F T F
```